# Intellij idea quick defenition

Tags: intellij-idea

In eclipse when I mouse over a variable I see it quick defenition, when I mouse over with shift pressed, I see full defenition. But in idea, I always need to press some keys to do anything. Is there a way to simplify those tasks in idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick definition features is accessible with the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.
I don't think it's possible to access to it on a key + the mouse over.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the `idea.properties` found in the `bin` folder of IntelliJ application and add this line:

```
auto.show.quick.doc=true
```

The

This will give you the JavaDoc when hovering over a variable:

[image]

Comment: I don't want javadoc, I want defenition in pop-up.

Comment: @dhblah So what's wrong with just Ctrl + mouse over variable?